# rubymotion _UIGetScreenImage

Tags: ios, app-store, rubymotion

We have tried submitting our app to the store a few times now, but keep getting flagged for a method: "_UIGetScreenImage".  We have no instances of this method anywhere in our code and have been unable to find any in our third party libraries.  I wonder if there is something else about our app that is causing Apple to flag it for this method?  Any help is appreciated.

Here is our Rakefile

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/ios'

begin
  require 'motion-cocoapods'
  require 'bundler'
  require 'bubble-wrap/mail'
  require 'motion-installr'
 # require 'motion-blitz'
  Bundler.require
rescue LoadError
end

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
  app.name = 'urvirl'
  app.icons = ['Icon.png', 'Icon-72@2x.png', 'Icon-72.png', 'Icon-Small-20.png', 'Icon-Small-20@2x.png','Icon-Small-30.png','Icon-Small-30@2x.png', 'Icon-Small-50.png','Icon-Small-50@2x.png','Icon-Small.png', 'Icon-Small@2x.png', 'Icon.png', 'Icon@2x.png', 'apple-touch-icon-120x120.png', 'apple-touch-icon-152x152.png', 'apple-touch-icon-76x76.png']
  app.version = "1.0.11"
  app.identifier = 'com.ourcomp.urvirl'
  app.device_family = [:iphone]
  app.detect_dependencies = false
  app.interface_orientations = [:portrait]
  app.development do
    app.entitlements["aps-environment"] = "development"
    app.provisioning_profile = '/Users/mac/downloads/app_development.mobileprovision'
    app.codesign_certificate = 'iPhone Developer: John Q (myId)'
  end
  # Building for Ad Hoc or App Store distribution
  app.release do
    app.entitlements["aps-environment"] = "production"
    app.codesign_certificate = 'iPhone Distribution:Company, Inc (compId)'
    app.provisioning_profile = '/Users/mac/downloads/urvirl_release.mobileprovision'
  end
  app.info_plist["UIRequiresFullScreen"] = true
  app.info_plist['NSAppTransportSecurity'] = {
      'NSExceptionDomains' => {
          'http://our_api.com' => { 'NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads' => true }
      }
  }
  app.info_plist['NSAppTransportSecurity'] = { 'NSAllowsArbitraryLoads' => true }
  app.info_plist["LSRequiresIPhoneOS"] = true
  app.fonts = ['tw-cent-bold.ttf']

  app.frameworks += [
    'QuartzCore'
  ]

  app.pods do
    pod 'TMReachability', :git => 'https://github.com/albertbori/Reachability', :commit => 'e34782b386307e386348b481c02c176d58ba45e6'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD', :head
    pod 'UITextView+Placeholder'
    pod 'SSKeychain'
    pod 'ViewDeck', '~> 2.4'
  end
end
```

And our Gemfile:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rake'
# Add your dependencies here:

gem 'ruby_motion_query', github: 'infinitered/rmq'

gem 'motion-calabash'

gem 'motion-support'
gem 'motion-keychain'

gem 'bubble-wrap'
gem 'bubble-wrap-http'

gem 'motion-cocoapods'

gem 'motion-installr'

gem 'motion-firebase'
```

And our app_delegate.rb

```
class AppDelegate

  attr_accessor :window, :centerController, :leftController

  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)

    chat_controller = ChatController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
    contact_controller = ContactController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)

    rightController = RightViewController.alloc.init



    self.centerController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(AuthenticationController.alloc.init)
    deckController = IIViewDeckController.alloc.initWithCenterViewController(self.centerController,
                                                                              rightViewController: rightController
                                                                            )
    deckController.rightSize = 70
    @window.rootViewController = deckController

    @window.makeKeyAndVisible

    true

  end

  def applicationDidBecomeActive(application)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
  end

  def application(application, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: notificationSettings)  
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications
  end 



  def application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: device_token)  
    # Save the device token back to the Rails app.
    # The token first needs to be converted to a string before saving
    string = token_to_string(device_token)
    MotionKeychain.set('device_id', string)
  end

  def token_to_string(device_token)  
    device_token.description.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.characterSetWithCharactersInString("<>")).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
  end 

  def application(application, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: error)  
    NSLog("%@", error.localizedDescription)
  end  
end
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, there is a screenshot reference in the gem 'motion-calabash', remove this gem for production and the build will succeed.